# Moving multiple tables between MS SQL Servers using only script

Tags: sql, sql-server, copy

How can I move multiple tables between SQL servers (but not every table of the database)?

I have a list of the tables that need to be copied. Is there any way to create an enum (or something like that) from this list, and loop through the items, to create a dynamic script?

I already created a Linked Server connection, the script should work with this method. Identity insert also need to be used in the script.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: have you looked into using dynamic sql and then iterate through your list of tables

Comment: Could you not just generate scripts w/ SSMS for both schema and data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only should take care of the @dest and @tables.

```
declare @tables varchar(MAX)
declare @t varchar(50)
declare @sql varchar(MAX)
declare @dest varchar(80)

set @dest = 'myNewServer.newDb..';
set @tables = '[Table1], [Table2]'


while len(@tables) > 0
begin
  --print left(@tables, charindex(',', @tables+',')-1)
  set @t = left(@tables, charindex(',', @tables+',')-1)
  set @sql = 'select * into "+ @dest + @t + ' from '+@t
  set @tables = stuff(@tables, 1, charindex(',', @tables+','), '')

  execute(@sql)

end
```

This methods copies all the tabes data, preserving IDs because:

"... this doesn't copy any of the metadata other than the column information (names & datatypes). So it will not have security permissions, indexes, triggers, constraints. etc. That said the Management Studio example above also has the same problem." from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337553.aspx

Comment: well destination could easily be selected in the same manner as the table from string

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks!

Any advice about keeping the identity properties of the tables?

Comment: This method copies only names and data types of columns. No other metadata. No conctraints, no keys, foreign keys.

Comment: You might want to copy database and remove unnecesary tables from there to preserve everything as is. Otherwise you'll probably need a bunch of scripts or use wizards